# transforming xml to html using xslt

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt

**What I am doing**: I am trying to transform xml to html using xslt.

---

**Question**: The program is executing without any error, it is gproducing the output file also, but it does not transform the xml to html. My guess is that the `for` loop in the xsl is not fetching the data.

---

**XSLTTest.java**

```
 package JavaXSLTExample;
import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
public class XSLTTest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /*if (args.length != 3)
    {
        System.err.println("give command as follows : ");
        System.err.println("XSLTTest data.xml converted.xsl converted.html");
        return;
    }*/
    String dataXML = "C:\\Users\\Devrath\\Desktop\\XSL\\FileOne.xml";
    String inputXSL = "C:\\Users\\Devrath\\Desktop\\XSL\\FileTwo.xsl";
    String outputHTML = "C:\\Users\\Devrath\\Desktop\\XSL\\output1.html";

    XSLTTest st = new XSLTTest();
    try
    {
        st.transform(dataXML, inputXSL, outputHTML);
    }
    catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)
    {
        System.err.println("TransformerConfigurationException");
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    catch (TransformerException e)
    {
        System.err.println("TransformerException");
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    }

    public void transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL, String outputHTML)
    throws TransformerConfigurationException,
    TransformerException
    {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
        StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputHTML);
        transformer.transform(in, out);
        System.out.println("The generated HTML file is:" + outputHTML);
    }
}
```

**FileOne.xml**

```
<languages-list>
  <language>
    <name>Kannada</name>
    <region>Karnataka</region>
    <users>38M</users>
  <family>Dravidian</family>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Telugu</name>
    <region>Andra Pradesh</region>
    <users>74M</users>
    <family>Dravidian</family>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Tamil</name>
    <region>TamilNadu</region>
    <users>61M</users>
    <family>Dravidian</family>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Malayalam</name>
    <region>Kerela</region>
    <users>33M</users>
    <family>Dravidian</family>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Hindi</name>
    <region>Andaman and Nicobar Islands, North india, Parts of North east</region>
    <users>442M</users>
    <family>Indo Aryan</family>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Assamese</name>
    <region>Assam, Arunachal Pradesh</region>
    <users>13M</users>
    <family>Indo Aryan</family>
  </language>
</languages-list>
```

**FileTwo.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Indian Languages details</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Language</th>
                        <th>Family/Origin</th>
                        <th>No. of speakers</th>
                        <th>Region</th>
                    </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="language-list/language">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="family"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="users"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="region"/></td>
                    </tr>
                 </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Indian Languages details</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Language</th><th>Family/Origin</th><th>No. of speakers</th><th>Region</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Come on ... You start your XML with the root element "languages-list" but then you refer to "language-list" in your XSLT ?!

Comment: You might like to know that with schema-aware XSLT 2.0, that trivial error might have been caught for you at compile time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XML is very unforgiving. This:

```
     <xsl:for-each select="language-list/language">
```

needs to be:

```
     <xsl:for-each select="languages-list/language">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing language(s)-list does not make the program error free. It fails with error as below:

```
Error on line 7 of FileTwo.xsl:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
TransformerException
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
```

This is misleading because it does not point to the actual problem.
The problem is with "outputHTML" it should be of a type File or FileOutputStream.

I have tried with File and it worked. 
So this statement:

```
StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputHTML);
```

is rewritten as:

```
StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new File(outputHTML));
```

Ofcourse import java.io.File

Using FileOutputStream needs appropriate code tweaking and import statements.